# Importing matplotlib using PyScripter

Tags: python, matplotlib, import

I am using PyScripter as an IDE for python coding. I installed matplotlib in windows.Now i written a program which imports matplotlib but PyScripter doesn't import this lib.How i can matplotlib using PyScripter.

Answer (score 1):

This might be very late :-) but to those browsing - Pyscripter can connect to the internal bundled python installation and to your global installation (as a remote engine). Packages imported to the global will not be available in the internal engine. Just connect to remote, and you should be good.